# Dynamically reduce the array size in classic ASP

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, vbscript

I have an array. I loop through it and display the value. Once displayed, I want to remove that particular node so that the array size reduces.

Example

```
tot = 20
redim values(tot)
for i=1 to 20
  values(i) = i
next

for i=1 to ubound(values)
  if values(i) = 10 then
    ' i do my work here.
    ' After my work is done, i want to remove the node values(10) 
    ' so that the ubound of my array changes to 19 and not 20 
    ' when i loop through next time.
  end if
next
```

Please help.

Comment: You could create a second, empty array and only add items you do not wish to delete to it. After your function is complete you can then set the original array to the amended one.

Comment: Is there a reason the item has to be deleted from the array? You're burning more memory and processor time by constantly `redim`-ing the array or almost any other option than you are likely to be using by just leaving it as-is. The answer to that question probably ought to be added to your original question to help future answerers.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you have to use an array? A dictionary object or an in-memory recordset could also be used with better performance and still allow for addition/deletion without the overhead of a `redim` or other method of dealing with re-sizing arrays. The answer to that question probably ought to be added to your original question to help future answerers.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of your array and keep the values using [Redim Preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

To remove a node, you could try this:

```
tot = 19
redim values(tot)

for i=0 to UBound(values)
  values(i) = i+1
next

Response.write  "Initial Size:"& UBound(values) & "<br/>"

bMoveUp = false

for i=0 to ubound(values)


   if values(i) = 10 then
    'do your thing with the i=10 the element

    bMoveUp = true
   end if

    if bMoveUp = true Then
    if i <> ubound(values)  then
        values(i) = values(i+1)
    end if
    End If


next

Redim Preserve Values(ubound(values)-1)

Response.write "Final Size:"& UBound(values) & "<br/>"


for i=0 to UBound(Values)
  Response.write values(i) &  "<br/>"
next
```

Comment: that can be used to increase the array size.. what if I have to remove a specific code. ? can you help me with an example where the array size is reduced.. ??